# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

When I installed Acumatica 2021R2 ERP 21.202.0054 and create an instance, After that when i try to login i am getting this error. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in acumatica

Answer (score 0):

Try running the ERP Configuration wizard / Maintain Application / Upgrade function and see if that clears up your error. More often than not it will help with instances that are throwing errors.